# Settings pages doesn't display properly after dist-upgrade

Tags: gnome, upgrade, nautilus

I added the main Gnome PPA to get latest "Nautilus" version. Because Ubuntu repository has old one. After dist-upgrade mouse cursor disappeared I already fix it. Also settings page do not display properly.

Ubuntu picture on details windows has been gone and lots of windows has been transparent. Although I set "Menus have icon" with Ubuntu Tweak, menus have no icon.

[image]

[image]

Other Pictures are here. (http://ow.ly/vNoxy) or direct links:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ekh0x.png 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yjsN.png 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xi3JY.png

How can I fix?